# Doxygen in C: check format/style

Tags: c

I want to keep consistent Doxygen format/style in my project. In example:

```
/**
 * @brief Brief description.
 * 
 * Longer description.........................
 * perhaps multi-line.
 * 
 * - List of things.
 * - List of things.
 *
 * @samestuff Foo.
 * @samestuff Bar.
 *
 * @otherstuff Asdf.
 *
 * [...]
 */
```

Is there a tool to check correct format/style? In example:

- All lines have a maximum length.
- First line is always `/**`.
- Last line is always `*/`.
- There is always a `@brief`.
- All intermediate lines starts with `*` (one space before and after the `*`).
- List items have one space after `-`.
- Different `@whatever` are separated with a blank line.
- All paragraphs or list items end with `.`.

Ideally it would also:

- Check that there is a `@return` if the function returns non void.
- Check all parameters have a `@param`.

I am not interested in a tool to check *this* particular set of rules, but a tool to check *a* particular set of rules. That means, I do not mind adhering to one or another set of rules, but I would love to adhere to one and include this verification in the CI tests, so that we all write the code with the same style (I already have some checker for code style, but have not found a checker for doxygen comment style).

Comment: I have not enough reputation here to add a new tag but doxygen is mentioned in the header and comments but no tagged, might give better exposure to have it tagged with doxygen or cross post it to doxygen as well (as it is not directly a doxygen question, but maybe a doxygen user has some experience with this kind checking). Would also be of interest to know something more about the tool you se "I already have some checker for code style" as when it checks C-code it should be able to do comment checks as well (and might be extendable).

Comment: @albert Yeah, I would have added that tag if I had reputation too, but I do not. ^^ The tool I am using is `checkpatch.pl`, a script using for checking code style in the Linux kernel project. It does not do comment checks.